# Spring rest controller to filter a resource

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

In my spring boot application, I have a Question as a resource, with following fields.

```
    [  
       {  
          "questionId":6,
          "area":"TECHNICAL",
          "title":"Find the index of first 1 in an infinite sorted array of 0s and 1s",
          "description":"Given an infinite sorted array consisting 0s and 1s. The problem is to find the index of first 1 in that array. As the array is infinite, therefore it is guaranteed that number 1 will be present in the array.",
          "state":"ACTIVE",
          "difficultyLevel":"EASY",
          "skills":[  
             {  
                "skillId":1,
                "skillName":"ALGORITHM"
             },
             {  
                "skillId":2,
                "skillName":"PROGRAMMING"
             }
          ],
          "proposedBy":"agrawalo",
          "noOfTimesUsed":0,
          "examples":null,
          "probes":null,
          "approvedBy":null,
          "addedBy":null,
          "dateCreated":"2018-05-16T19:29:11.113",
          "dateLastUpdated":"2018-05-16T19:29:11.113"
       }, 
       {
        ...
       },
       ...
    ]
```

I want to write controllers to filter questions.

For example:

1./questions?area="technical". A controller that returns questions with area as "technical". For this I wrote following method.

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController { 
    @RequestMapping("/questions",  method = GET)
    String getFilteredQuestions(@RequestParam("area") String questionArea) {

    }
}
```

2./questions?area="technical"&skill="programming". Now, I want to write a controller that returns question with area as "technical" and skill as "programming".

One way I can achieve this is by adding one more request param to the "getFilteredQuestion" method.

But with that I will end up writing a very messy code (say if I want to add more filters) that checks what request param is null and what is not and based on that apply filters.

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController {
    @RequestMapping("/questions",  method = GET)
    String getFilteredQuestions(@RequestParam("area") String questionArea, @RequestParam("skill") String questionSkill) {

    }
}
```

3./questions?skill="algorithm"&proposedby="agrawalo" ...

Any clean way of writing such controllers?

Comment: You can use library rsql-parser https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539774/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can write Question class as an Entity class.

```
public class Question {
         private String title;
         private String description;
         private List<String> skills;
         private Date createdAt;

         public void setTitle(String title) {
             this.title = title;
         }
         public String getTitle() {
             return this.title;
         }

    }
```

And then in this way you can get your data like that

```
@RestController
public class QuestionController {
    @RequestMapping("/questions",  method = GET)
    String getFilteredQuestions@RequestBody Question question) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that calling that object an _Entity_ is appropriate. It is a temporary object that is valid only for a single request. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html

Comment: You can do this QuestionDto

Comment: Yes, DTO would be more suitable. Moreover, be aware, that _bodies_ in GET requests are discouraged. Nevertheless, if you don't stick to restful principles pedantically, the solution you suggest is frequently applied, using the POST method, though.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Java POJO with all the query and filter parameters you support. Make sure you can map that POJO to JSON and vice versa. Your client can edit the JSON version and send it along with the request. You map it back to your POJO and pass it to the business logic that takes care of preparing the appropriate query. That way, you can leave your Controller's methods untouched.

Comment: Any example reference or can you please help me with the real code to solve a use-case mentioned above?

Comment: Take a look at Jackson object mapping, e.g. https://springframework.guru/processing-json-jackson/
You could serialize the query JSON object and append it to your URL like /questions?query=<serializedstring>, if you like to stick to GET requests.